# Selecting multiple names with different field SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am new to the SQL language. Just learned it for 4 months.

My assignment question is to find the supplier who does not supply beverages.

Using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN` (and `INNER JOIN` should be fine too).

I was given 3 tables.

```
SELECT 
    S.ContactName    
FROM 
    Suppliers AS S    
INNER JOIN    
    Products AS P ON S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID    
LEFT OUTER JOIN    
    Categories AS C ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID    
WHERE 
    C.CategoryName != 'Beverages'    
GROUP BY 
    S.ContactName
```

I've tried using the above code, but it seems to return multiple names. For example supplier 'Anne Heikkonen' supplies both beverages and others. But when I use the above select statement, it removes only her name that has the CategoryName 'Beverage' While ignoring her other counter-part.
[Output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9bQV.png) As you can see, supplier 'Anne Heikkonen' still appears in the results as she serves both beverages and others.

[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gB1PQ.png)

[Categories Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCHcd.png)

[Supplier Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYrfa.png)

Comment: This is a faq. Google clear statements of your problem/goal/question. Read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
select s.name
 from supplier
where not exists (select 1 
                    from product p
                    join category c on c.category_id = p.category_id
                   where c.category_name = 'Beverages'
                     and p.supplier_id = s.supplier_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the `not exists` approach, getting your approach to work is worthwhile.

The thinking is:  Get all suppliers and match to the beverage category using a `left join`.  Then use a `where` clause to see if there is a match.

So this looks like:

```
SELECT S.ContactName    
FROM Suppliers S LEFT JOIN    
     Products P
     ON S.SupplierID = P.SupplierID LEFT JOIN    
     Categories C
     ON C.CategoryID = P.CategoryID AND   
        C.CategoryName = 'Beverages'  -- attempt the match
WHERE C.CategoryId IS NULL;  -- find there is no match
```